# GWT Compiler & Source Codes

Tags: java, gwt

I have a general question about gwt compilation.

When I open gwt-dev.jar I can see some common packages like javax.xml.parsers 
What is the reason for having these common classes here ? I know GWT compiler need all java sources but I can't find any .java file inside gwt-dev !

I am confused, when I am inserting javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder, compiler says Source not found, that s fine because it should not be part of JRE emulation, but why we have this class inside gwt-dev ?!!!

Second question is where are the JRE source files for gwt compiler ?

I appreciate anyone can leave me a link for this concept ....

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GWT Compiler is written in Java, and as such needs a whole lot of code to parse your code. A GWT application is defined by a GWT Module, in the form of an XML file, so the GWT Compiler needs an XML parser; this is why you find XML-related classes in gwt-dev (you'll also find the Eclipse JDT used to parse your Java code, the Jetty server and various servlet dependencies used by the DevMode, etc.)

To answer your second question, the classes you can use in your client code are in gwt-user, and the Java Runtime emulation is in `com/google/gwt/emul/`.